# How to load bean without using ApplicationContext or ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in SpringData JPA

Tags: repository, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring Data JPA.I facing problem in loading bean without using ApplicationContext or ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.Because in my current project I have one old spring related jar which cannot be removed.Because of which my current "SpringContext.xml" cannot be loaded.Here is my code which prevent from loading SpringContext.xml

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringContext.xml");
RegistrationBean registrationBean = (RegistrationBean)context.getBean("registrationBean");
```

Here is my RegistrationBean for my Repository

```
@Component
public class RegistrationBean {
@Autowired
private CreditorProfileRepository creditorProfileReposigtory;

public RegistrationBean(){

}
public CreditorProfileRepository getCreditorProfileReposigtory() {
    return creditorProfileReposigtory;
}
public void setEmployeeReposigtory(CreditorProfileRepository creditorProfileReposigtory) {
    this.creditorProfileReposigtory = creditorProfileReposigtory;
}
```

}

Here is my repository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface CreditorProfileRepository extends CrudRepository <CreditorProfile, String>{
public CreditorProfile  findBympcreditorprofileidpk(String  mpcreditorprofileidpk);
}
```

So I  taught of using constructor injection to load registrationBean in my application class.Here is my application class

```
public class CreateCreditorProfile implements ICreateCreditorProfile{

RegistrationBean repositoryRegistration;

CreateCreditorProfile(RegistrationBean repositoryRegistration){
    this.repositoryRegistration=repositoryRegistration;
}

CreateCreditorProfile(){
    this.repositoryRegistration=repositoryRegistration;
}
@Override
public void createCreditorProfile(CreditorProfileServiceDetails creditorProfileServiceDetails) {
            CreditorProfile creditorProfile = new CreditorProfile();
            creditorProfile.setcreditorprofileidpk("343243243");
            creditorProfile.setpartyid("000005");
            creditorProfile.setpartyname("Federico o Peluso");

            repositoryRegistration.getCreditorProfileReposigtory().save(creditorProfile);
}
```

Here is my ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="registrationBean" class="com.mi.bn.payment.persistence.RegistrationBean" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="CreateCreditorProfile" class="com.mi.bn.paymen.persistence.CreateCreditorProfile" scope="prototype" >
    <constructor-arg name="repositoryRegistration" ref="registrationBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="creditorsProfileConfiguration" class="com.mi.bn.payment.domain.configuration.CreditorsProfileConfiguration" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg name="creater" ref="CreateCreditorProfile" />
</bean>
```

Here is my SpringContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<!-- For consider the using of annotations foe defining Spring Bean -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- For defining Spring Bean -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cs.ed.paymentmessaging.persistence" />

<!-- For bootstrapping the Spring Repository -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.cs.ed.paymentmessaging.persistence" />

<!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DD23"/>
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
         <property name="username" value="db2admin"/>
         <property name="password" value="Wasadm1n"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpringData"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Enable Transactional Manner -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

But still it is my application class I get null pointer exception at

> repositoryRegistration.getCreditorProfileReposigtory().save(creditorprofile)

So Please let me know workaround for this problem.

Here is stack trace

```
11:03:04,725 INFO  [CommandExecuter] An Unexpected Error Occurred An Unexpected Error Occurred java.lang.NullPointerException
com.trapedza.bankfusion.core.BankFusionException: An Unexpected Error Occurred java.lang.NullPointerException
    at                     com.misys.bankfusion.subsystem.microflow.runtime.command.ExecuteMicroflowCommand.createBankFusionException(ExecuteMicroflowCommand.java:1224)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.subsystem.microflow.runtime.command.ExecuteMicroflowCommand.execute(ExecuteMicroflowCommand.java:674)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.command.impl.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:596)
    at com.trapedza.bankfusion.servercommon.commands.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:392)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.command.impl.CommandExecuter.executeCommand(CommandExecuter.java:435)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.controller.ExecutionModeHelper.executeDirect(ExecutionModeHelper.java:142)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.controller.ExecutionModeHelper.executeCommand(ExecutionModeHelper.java:121)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.controller.ExecutionController.executeCommand(ExecutionController.java:121)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.controller.CommandUtils.executeCommand(CommandUtils.java:66)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.uxp.plugin.BankFusionServicePlugin.processOtherRequests(BankFusionServicePlugin.java:799)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.uxp.plugin.BankFusionServicePlugin.executeService(BankFusionServicePlugin.java:191)
    at com.misys.uxp.container.servlet.UXServlet.service(UXServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.misys.bankfusion.paymentmessaging.persistence.CreateCreditorProfile.createCreditorProfile(CreateCreditorProfile.java:65)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.paymentmessaging.domain.configuration.CreditorsProfileConfiguration.createCreditorProfile(CreditorsProfileConfiguration.java:34)
    at com.misys.bankfusion.paymentmessaging.controller.fatom.MaintainCreditorProfiles.process(MaintainCreditorProfiles.java:46)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the NPE?

Comment: @swinkler NPE..means ?

Comment: NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Your RegistrationBean seems not to be autowired:

```
public class CreateCreditorProfile implements ICreateCreditorProfile{
     @Autowired
     RegistrationBean repositoryRegistration;
...
}
```

Regarding your question why the constructor call is not working, as far as I can see there are 2 context.xml declarations - ApplicationContext.xml and SpringContext.xml. You need to load both of them:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
  "SpringContext.xml","ApplicationContext.xml");
```

Or you can import the Application.xml inside the SpringContext.xml

```
<import resource="ApplicationContext.xml" />
```

Both ways should result in loading your beans properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer swinkler.But can I know why constructor injection is not happening here.